# Linked Structures in Visual Basic; is it possible to implement a double reference?

Tags: vb.net

When one is traversing a linked structure with the intent of acting upon the structure (i.e.: inserting a node into a simple linked list as a trivial example,) one obtains the best algorithm by pushing a double pointer through the structure; if a single reference is used, then one must write one or more special cases for null roots and/or tail insertions.

```
node_type **dp = &root;

while(*dp && /insertion point not reached/)
dp=&(*dp)->next;
```

When I fall out of the loop, *dp is the point of insertion into the list; I'm holding a reference to the object's link.  This reference might be to the root, a null object at the end of the structure, or any other node.  As the structure becomes more complex, the need for a double-reference becomes more pronounced as the need for special cases tends to grow exponentially.

How does one implement a double-reference in Visual Basic?

Note: the linked list bit only serves as an example... I know: there are lots of ways around that simple issue.

Comment: Just wrap the reference into a class of which you then take the reference. Done.

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand.  Can you give a simple example?

Comment: In general, VB doesn't deal with low level pointers.  We only use high level **references**.  How would you use this in VB?  Can you post your VB definition for a node in your linked list?

Comment: OK; however, I might fat-finger this web interface until I learn it. Class nodeType
        Public payLoad As String 'whatever
        Public pnext As nodeType
    End Class

Comment: How do I post formatted code?

Comment: After research, I do not believe that anything like a double pointer can be implemented in current versions of Visual Basic.  I see that many others have asked the same question; the most frequent answer seems to be: "Why do you need such a thing?"  Clearly, one who would ask, doesn't.

Comment: Are you looking for a VB.NET implementation of `a doubly linked list`? Regarding your last comment, well, the thing is, for most applications, even the most complex enterprise class apps, you never need such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse the C#, my VB.NET is rather rusty. The only way to safely do double references in C#/VB.NET is using a `ref` parameter to a method.

```cs
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an example root node. This example still works when root
            // is null.
            Node root = new Node() { next = new Node() };

            // Setup a Node that contains a pointer to root. This variable will
            // not be destroyed by iteration and rp.next will always be root
            // after iteration, even if root started as null.
            Node rp = new Node() { next = root };

            // Initialize the iterator to the root pointer.
            Node dp = rp;

            // Define a new node to be inserted for this example.
            Node nn1 = new Node();
            Node nn2 = new Node();

            // Iterate by calling DoWork until a null reference is returned.
            // Note that a reference to dp.next is passed to the method. This
            // allows the method to change what dp.next points to. The node to
            // insert is also given to the method. You could easily change this
            // second parameter to be an action that works on the desired node.
            while(null != (dp = DoWork(ref dp.next, nn1))) { }
            dp = rp;
            while(null != (dp = DoWork(ref dp.next, nn2))) { }

            // Force root to be assigned. If root did not start as null this
            // line is unnecessary.
            root = rp.next;
        }

        private static Node DoWork(ref Node node, Node nn)
        {
            // Logic to determine if the insertion point is not reached. For
            // this example the new node is always inserted just before the tail.
            bool logic = null != node && null != node.next;

            // Check node and logic. Return the node to continue iterating.
            if(null != node && logic)
            {
                return node;
            }

            // Insertion logic here. For the example the new node is inserted
            // into the linked list.
            nn.next = node;
            node = nn;

            // Return null to signify that iteration has completed.
            return null;
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{id} - {next}")]
    class Node
    {
        private static int sID;

        public int id;
        public Node next;

        public Node()
        {
            id = ++sID;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After research, I conclude that the answer is similar to: "What if you're *way* too drunk to drive but you really need to drive, anyway?"  Answer: it's easy, don't drive.

Garbage collected languages, e.g.: Visual Basic, cannot allow a distinction between a collected variable and a reference to the same.  Do I *need* a double reference?  Of course I do!  Is there a way to get one in a garbage collected language?  No... it would break the garbage collector if I could do such a thing.

Well, I was hoping that there was some magic answer... drink lots of coffee?  I'll just have to live with the fact that there is no such animal as a "double reference" in Visual Basic and find a way around it.

Smith